# Disable Commerce 3 shipping altogether

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to disable the shipping feature altogether in Commerce 3?

A shipping step decreases sales up to 30%.

I have some quirky CSS hiding shenanigans going on in my templates to hide the shipping link. That is not a great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out the complete step, not only by hiding the link. Also make sure, the shipping costs are not shown in your template anymore. And no shipping rules.